Linestx when no data is available on x axis
I have created the DAX for linestx below -
Revenue trend =
VAR line =
LINESTX (
ALLSELECTED('Sales order line fact'[Order month]), -- This respects the slicer
[Total revenue trend],
'Sales order line fact'[Order month]
)
VAR slope = SELECTCOLUMNS(line, [Slope1])
VAR intercept = SELECTCOLUMNS(line, [Intercept])
VAR x = SELECTEDVALUE('Sales order line fact'[Order month])
VAR y = x * slope + intercept
RETURN y

My data has some gaps between them
May and June are not available

PBI is giving some weird results for those months.  However, I need  PBI to consider the total revenue trend as 0 and then calculate the revenue trend. Revenue trend for May and June should be around if total revenue is 0 for those months
57838.21    ,51566.91

Can you please provide some data ?input and expected output?
